# Creating a custom template tag to replace the for loop - Django

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

I am trying to simplify my code by creating a custom template tag for a 'for loop' that use frequently on my Django web application. I thought it would be a simple straight process, but something isn't working right... I can use some assistance in catching my error.

Here is my code.
views.py

```
 class ArticleView(DetailView):
    model = Articles

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(ArticleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['s_terms'] = scientific_terms.objects.all()
      return context
```

template tag

```
@register.filter(name='term')
def term(value):
  {% for term in s_terms %}
        {{ term.short_description }}
  {% endfor %}
```

template.html

```
{% Neurons|term %}
```

Thank you for your assistance, in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Python code with the Django Template Language. The template tags are plain Python code, as they are defined inside a Python module. A working example would be:

```
@register.filter(name='term')
def term(terms):
  output = ''
  for term in terms:
      output = '{0} {1}'.format(output, term.short_description)
  return output
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
{{ s_terms|term }}
```

Maybe what you want is simply to create a reusable Django template.

For example, create a new template named **terms.html**:

**templates/terms.html**

```
{% for term in terms %}
    <p>{{ term.short_description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Then, in another template, you could *include* this partial template:

**templates/index.html** (name is just an example)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My application</h1>
    {% include 'terms.html' with terms=s_terms %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Victor, I really like your second response, but I can't get it to work. Say for example, I set up a different template, that shows data from the Scientific_terms model. How can I "include" the dynamic page rather than just the template?